# Compile error: End if without block if - Firing despite complete block

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that won't run due to an end if block error. As far as I can tell, the block is complete. When I do attempt to run, the Sub LoopThrough Directory() is highlighted as the error, and I'm not quite sure why.

```
Sub LoopThroughDirectory()

Dim MyFile As Variant
Dim wkb As Workbook

Filepath = "\\WFSIADMNSF21\C_MTG_Groups\DAPLAVA\Monthly Vendor Files\Pres\"

MyFile = Dir(Filepath)

Do While Len(MyFile) > 0
    If MyFile <> "PFORMAT.xlsm" Then
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        Set wkb = Workbooks.Open(Filepath & MyFile)
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False

**I have 1500 lines of code between here, but no additional if statements, and nothing matches the indentation of the If statement**

  End With
    wkb.Close savechanges:=True
    End If

    MyFile = Dir

Loop
Sheets("PFORMAT").Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Where is the `With` to go with the `End With`? It might be worth sharing the rest of your code, as that's the only thing that pops up here...

Comment: Is \WFSIADMNSF21\C_MTG_Groups\DAPLAVA\Monthly Vendor Files\Pres\ definitely a valid path?

Comment: *I have 1500 lines of code between here* - time to refactor your code into small subroutines that are called as needed. Sounds like a **nightmare** to manage / troubleshoot (as you are experiencing)

Comment: You should also **Require Variable Declaration** (VBE Tools ~ Options ~ Editor tab).  This will place `Option Explicit` at the top of each new module you create and force you to declare variables beforehand - such as `FilePath`.

Comment: A refactor is probably the way to go. I was hoping there was some nuanced factor I was overlooking, but I guess not. Back to the drawing board, thanks for the posts.

Comment: This is why you should properly indent your code. It's not just there to make your code look pretty.

Comment: Which part of that was indented incorrectly?

Comment: @degeest12 Well for starters, `End With` Is way to the left but it's between your `If..Then` statement. Also `wkb.Close` isn't indented within the same `If...Then` statement.

Comment: And why you even have 1500 lines of code within an IF statement is unknown to me. Once you figure out what is causing your issue then you should probably take your code to [codereview.se]

Comment: I don't think it's an indentation problem. The if statement is aligned. When I remove the function to test, I got an error for the "Loop" not being linked to "Do", which is also aligned. The funny thing is I run a nearly identical macro, with just different file path and values, and it works fine.